Question On Combinatorial Game Theory
Let $n$ be a positive integer. $A$ and $B$ play a game with $n$ cards.
First, $A$ writes one integer on each of $n$ cards. After that, $B$ repeats the following operations.
Choose two cards and let the integers written on them be $a$ and $b$.
Erase both numbers written on the chosen card and write $a – b$ on one card and $b – a$ on the other card.
The goal of $B$ is to make the numbers written on all cards $0$ after a finite number of operations.
(1) Show that when $n = 3$, $A$ can write integers so that $B$ cannot achieve its goal.
(2) Show that when $n = 4$, $B$ can always achieve its goal regardless of how A is written
I have noticed only one thing in the question -
a) The sum reduces by $a+b$ after each move

Please don't repost the same closed question repeatedly.  The first version was closed because you showed no effort at all, please edit that version to include some effort.  Surely the case of three cards is something you could at least try.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of the OP's prior question

This question is similar to: Combinatorics Games Question. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
